# Using Ratchet WsServer in combination with React SecureServer (WSS / SSL)

Tags: ssl, ratchet, reactphp

We are trying to implement websockets over secure connection (WSS) and have cboden/ratchet implemented in our project. All Works fine over normal connection. Looking around in the docs and the Github project pages, it seems te new React SecureServer class is not yet implemented in Ratchet.

In the issues we found [a post about it](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/pull/500), and it won't be supported untill later versions, however, we need it now :D
At the issue report they suggest using the new React SecureServer class in combination with Ratchet classes.. We tried and got a fatal error:

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to React\Socket\SecureServer::__construct() must be an instance of React\Socket\Server, instance of Ratchet\Http\HttpServer given.`

Part where it goes wrong:

```
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new React\Socket\SecureServer( // Using React class here as suggested
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock, 
    array(
        'local_cert' => 'xxxx.pem',
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false
    )
);
```

Are we doing something stupid? :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secure server is supposed to be wrapped around the socket server, not the HTTP server:

```
  $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
          new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
            $pusher
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    new React\Socket\SecureServer( // Using React class here as suggested
      $webSock,
      $loop,
      array(
        'local_cert' => 'xxxx.pem',
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: Ok, thx for the response. Now I am getting an error on the second argument: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to React\Socket\SecureServer::__construct() must implement interface React\EventLoop\LoopInterface, instance of React\ZMQ\Context given`

Comment: I assumed `$loop` is  the variable you store your event loop in, so which ever variable you stored it in, use that there.

Comment: Ah yes, I tried using $context since I thought it returned $loop instance.
The server seems to be running again now... Browsers can not connect though. We get a `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP` error code. Is there a way to specify which type of encryption to use?

Comment: The [SecureServer](https://reactphp.org/socket/#secureserver) supports all of PHP's [ssl context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php).

Comment: Uhu, I saw there is a cypher option. Not sure which one to set instead of ALL :D

Comment: Good luck ;). From what my quick search on `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP` gave me this might also be something you can fix on the browser side

Comment: Yes.. In FF you can fix it by fiddling in the about:config... But other clients are not going to do that by default.. We'll look for php-side solution. Many thanks for the help :)